# User login session variable. Is it possible to spoof session variable? PHP

Tags: php, session, authentication

When user logs in I use the following strategy to authenticate user:

1. **Username** and **Password** are present in database along with unique **Token** and **Session Identifier**
2. Set session variable `$_SESSION['logged_in'] = true` if above returns true
3. On every page (basecontroller) checks `if ($_SESSION['logged_in'] > 0)` otherwise redirects to login page.

Is it possible that a hacker might somehow set **$_SESSION['logged_in']  = true;** ? Do I have a security issue with the above strategy?

Please give me an article or anything that can help me make it more secure.

Comment: You need to implement two session validators as well : 1) IP 2) Agent

Comment: And also, you should wrap this all into a class

Comment: it is wrapped into a class. for the sake of example i put it that way

Comment: IP validation might be a bad idea for users behind corporate proxies where the  IP changes regularily. Checking the user agent is not very helpful either - if you can steal someone else's session ID you can surely get his UA string, too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sessions are stored on the server so it is impossible for a user to modify anything within the session unless he breaks into your server - in that case he could obviously run `$_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;` or perform anything else circumventing whatever security measures you have in your code.

The only thing stored on the client side is the session ID cookie. This is a random 32-character hash that does not contain any data.

Answer (score 0):

When using sessions in PHP, the visitors browser stores a cookie with nothing but a session ID stored in it. This session ID is passed back to your server on subsequent requests, and when you issue `session_start()` the server typically opens a file with the name of that unique session ID. This is where the data is stored.

The default session ID is pretty long, so it would take an attacker a long time to brute force and guess someone elses currently authenticated session. The cookie length can be adjusted if necessary.

As long as your sessions expire within a decent time frame, and the server properly removes the expired session data, you won't have any issues.

Answer (score 0):

A "Hacker" would not be able to set the session variable, unless you have some security issue in your code (no code -> no can tell, sorry)

But I see a problem in the provided code. Please use isset instead of >0 in step 3. A strict error setting would give you a warning here. Please only develop with strict error settings (better code, behaviour is predictable) and "normal" settings for live sites.

If you really have security concerns, pay a professional PHP programmer to check your code or post it here.

Comment: `isset` is a bad idea. He needs to check the value. Otherwise having it set to `false` would make the user logged in, too. `!empty()` would do the job, though.

Comment: why would I pay somebody to check my code I want to learn. When you pay someone to write code for you, you will never learn. And I do have isset() and also > 0 as for the sake of example I omitted those

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Maybe I forgot to add that part. Yeah, but without isset, the code will throw an error in case that the variable is not set. @ GGio: He should just check, not write. And only if you have concerns. If you just want to learn... I can't help you with the given code. The strategy is ok, I would say something trivial like this is the normal way to use a session for login in theaory (Of course there should be more info in the session, maybe also omitted?)